# Why token expiration time passed via env var not working

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have created the NodeJS API and an Auth system with in it using JWT. I set the token expiration in my env but in this way its not working and I have to write manually the time inside my function.

My function is a helper:

```
// RNV
const { Config } = require("../config");
// JWT
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Token helper
module.exports = {
    getToken: user => jwt.sign(user, Config.jwt.secret, { expiresIn: <ENV> })
};
```

It seems to be not working this way and I would like to understand the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question as I found a solution to my problem and maybe can be discussed :)

As from ENV is a String I had to convert it to a number int as it is accepting it the `expiresIn` and I used `parseInt(<env string>)` to get the right thing actually

```
// ENV
const { Config } = require("../config");
// JWT
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Token helper
module.exports = {
    getToken: user => jwt.sign(user, Config.jwt.secret, { expiresIn: parseInt(Config.jwt.expiration) } )
};
```

Comment: It works with casting to string as well i.e. `.env => JWT_EXPIRE=12h` and then 
```
module.exports = {
    getToken: user => jwt.sign(user, Config.jwt.secret, { expiresIn: String(process.env.JWT_EXPIRE) } )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this: `proccess.env.JWT_EXPIRE`.

```
// You env variable    
JWT_EXPIRE=12h
```

Then, in your javascript code:

```
// RNV
const { Config } = require("../config");
// JWT
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Token helper
module.exports = {
    getToken: user => jwt.sign(user, Config.jwt.secret, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE })
};
```

Comment: I did this I put 60 which is in seconds but is not working in this way for some reason.

Comment: How are you setting your variables?

Comment: I have in my env JWT_EXPIRATION = 60 then I call process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION

Comment: What is the output of node -e `"console.log(process.env)"` in your command line?

Comment: I found a solution becasue from env is in a string I had to convert to int like
{ expiresIn: parseInt(Config.jwt.expiration) }
Then is working :)

Comment: As string, the only thing you need to do is to add the time unit `60s`

Comment: Yes that should do also